# How do I make the logo appear at the top left of the split background and not show up below it?

Tags: html, css

```css
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}

.wrapper { 
    width: 1170px; 
    margin: auto; 
}

.logo img { 
    width: 84px; 
    float: left; 
    padding-left: 5%; 
    padding-top: 2%; 
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> <title>LoLstudy</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="fstyle.css" /> </head> <body> <div class="container"> <div class="left"></div>
```

here is the html code.
what shoud i do?

Comment: You need to share your html as well

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: you dont see it?

Comment: i need to make a split background and then add a logo to the top left

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: Your HTML isn't formatted which makes it hard to read with better formatting you would probably have picked up it's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `position: absolute` on the `.appbar` class to `position: fixed` or just remove the `position property` depending on the layout you want.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.appbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fragment {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.right {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="appbar">
    <a class="logo" href="#">LOGO</a>
  </header>

  <div class="fragment left">
    <h2>Left</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="fragment right">
    <h2>Right</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```